# Invoke a AWS Lambda function from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Can we invoke an AWS Lambda function from EC2 instances?

I have tried AWS Lambda invoking another Lambda, but not sure if we do can invoke from EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can invoke the Lambda from EC2 instance just like from any other machine.

Just use the boto3 call [invoke()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) or use the [cli to invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) it